# Remove gaps from geography

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, geography

I have a single geography consisting of 17 separate polygons. STNumGeometries() returns 17 for it as it should. On the largest polygon however I could see some narrow borders/cracks/gaps within the polygon. It seems I can hide them using STBuffer (see below), but the number of geometries increases. How can I remove the gaps without making the geography more complex?

```
select 
    myGeography.STNumGeometries() --Result: 17
    myGeography.STBuffer(+0.01).STBuffer(-0.01) --Result: I can no longer see lines within the largest polygon
    myGeography.STBuffer(+0.01).STBuffer(-0.01).STNumGeometries() --Result: 26
```

**Original:**

[image: Original]
[image: Original zoomed]

**Fixed:**

[image: Fixed]
[image: Fixed zoomed]

Comment: can you post a picture of what your polygon looks like and what is the result of the buffer?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added some pics

Comment: What are those in red circle?

Comment: Does `myGeography.MakeValid()` do anything?  I'm not entirely familiar with it but my understanding is that it will rearrange some of the points to "clean" them up.  Maybe that might help?

Comment: Beside make sure every one of the 17 geometry is Valid, Maybe some of those are multy geometry. So try checking each one of those 17 with `.STNumGeometries()`

Comment: Are each of the 17 shapes "simple"? That is, is the number of rings in each 1?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The marks I highlighted with red circles are the "gaps" I'm trying to remove. MakeValid() has no effect on those. How can I loop each of those 17 geometries within a geography?

Comment: `.STGeometryN(17)` returns that single faulty geometry that has those gaps.

,   myGeography.STGeometryN(17).STIsClosed() --1
,   myGeography.STGeometryN(17).STIsEmpty()  --0
,   myGeography.STGeometryN(17).STIsValid()  --1
,   myGeography.STGeometryN(17).STLength()   --17356.3125690373`
,   myGeography.STGeometryN(17).STNumGeometries()    --1

Comment: OK `.STGeometryN(17).MakeValid().NumRings()` returns 5, which seems to explain the gaps/lines within. How can I combine them into a single ring?

Comment: So geometry 17 consists of 5 LineStrings based on `.STGeometryN(17).RingN(<ordinal>).STGeometryType()`.

Comment: How can I check the area of each ring? Some of them look really narrow so their area is probably close to 0.

Comment: I think I want to remove the rings from each geometry where `.STGeometryN(17).RingN(5).Reduce(10).STNumPoints() <= 2`. The unnecessary rings have 4 points and about 0 area, after using reduce(10) they only have 2 points left. So how do I remove a ring from geometry?

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a method for removing "rings" from your geography that have very little area.** You can set the sensitivity by modifying the parameter for `Reduce()` function.

```
use myDB;

SELECT 
    myTable.pk
,   geography::UnionAggregate(      --Union polygons into a single geography
        geography::STGeomFromWKB(   --Linestring --> polygon
            0x01 + 0x03000000 + 0x01000000 + SUBSTRING(myTable.myGeography.STGeometryN(geometryN.number).RingN(ringN.number).STAsBinary(),6,2147483647) 
        ,   myTable.myGeography.STSrid
        )  
    )                                           as  shapeClean
FROM    mySchema.myTable
    inner join master.dbo.spt_values    as  geometryN
        on  geometryN."type"    =   'P' --only integers
        and geometryN.number    between 1 and myTable.myGeography.STNumGeometries()  --Number of geometries
    inner join master.dbo.spt_values    as  ringN
        on  ringN."type"        =   'P' --only integers
        and ringN.number        between 1 and myTable.myGeography.STGeometryN(geometryN.number).NumRings()   --Number of rings
where   myTable.pk = 4722
    and myTable.myGeography.STGeometryN(geometryN.number).RingN(ringN.number).Reduce(0.1).STNumPoints()  >   2   --Keep only rings that have some area even after "reducing" slightly
group by     myTable.pk
;
```